# Django forms custom backend validation

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, customvalidator, validationerror

I'm trying to run backend validations which takes ~3-4 seconds on 1 field (`query` field) only on POST request (i.e. only after the "Submit" button is clicked). 
When form is loaded on a GET request - i don't want to run this validation because it takes lot of time.

I tried to look on the [django form validation documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/)
But i couldn't understand a way to run the `clean` method only on a POST request. Anytime i'm creating a SomeForm instance, the `clean` method is taking place.

`forms.py`:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    is_active = forms.ChoiceField(label='Is Active?', required=False, choices=IS_ACTIVE_DROPDOWN)
    query = forms.CharField(label='Query',help_text='This is help text', widget=forms.Textarea)
    last_successful_run = forms.DateTimeField(label='Last Run')


    def clean(self):
        ... Execute "regular" cleaning ...
        return self.cleaned_data
```

`views.py`

```
def mng_tables_form(request, resource, action, item_id):
    form = SomeForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ## UPDATE DB
            api_driver.run_api_request(item_id, request.fields)
        return redirect('mng_tables_form_page', resource, 'show_item', item_id)

    else:
        form = _get_resource_objects(resource, RESOURCES_MODELS_MAPPING).get(action)
        ## Get Data from DB
        item_object = api_driver.run_api_request(resource=resource, item_id=item_id, params={'fields':form}).json().get('response')
        form = form(item_object)


    context = {'form': form,
               'item_object': item_object,
               'item_id': item_id}

    return render(request,
                  'mng_tables/form.html',
                  context=context)
```

What i want to do is to somehow recognize the request method when i create the form instance, and run more validation only if the method == 'POST':

```
    def clean(self):
        ... Execute "regular" cleaning ...
        ## Only on SUBMIT (request.POST)
        ... Run query field Backend validation ...
        if query is_valid:
            return self.cleaned_data
        else:
            raise ValidationError([
            ValidationError(_('query is not valid. please modify it and re-submit'), code='query')
```

EDIT:

following a small conversation with @devdob

I tried to DEBUG my code, trying to see why i get to the `clean` method also on GET requests.

on the GET part, the final return looks like:

```
views.py
return render(request,
                  'mng_tables/form.html',
                  context=context)
```

Which leads me to

```
django.shortcuts.py
def render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None):
    """
    Return a HttpResponse whose content is filled with the result of calling
    django.template.loader.render_to_string() with the passed arguments.
    """
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
    return HttpResponse(content, content_type, status)
```

Which leads me to look at the `render_to_string` function

```
django.template.loader.py
def render_to_string(template_name, context=None, request=None, using=None):
    """
    Load a template and render it with a context. Return a string.

    template_name may be a string or a list of strings.
    """
    if isinstance(template_name, (list, tuple)):
        template = select_template(template_name, using=using)
    else:
        template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
    return template.render(context, request)
```

which leads me to look at `get_template` function

```
django.template.loader.py
def get_template(template_name, using=None):
    """
    Load and return a template for the given name.

    Raise TemplateDoesNotExist if no such template exists.
    """
    chain = []
    engines = _engine_list(using)
    for engine in engines:
        try:
            return engine.get_template(template_name)
        except TemplateDoesNotExist as e:
            chain.append(e)

    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
```

And it gets me to the `clean` method when it tries to run:

```
return engine.get_template('bootstrap4/field.html')
```

I guess that my fields are configured to have bootstrap 4 design, but i don't know why it should effect anything.

Comment: You are already checking that in your view `request.method == 'POST'` then doing `if form.is_valid():`. You have checked if the method is POST and then checked for the validity of the form.

Comment: @devdob Your'e right, but somehow the `clean` method is running also when `request.method == 'GET'`. My problem is that the `clean` method runs ANY TIME a SomeForm instance is created

Comment: @devdob Is there a way to NOT call the `clean` method when creating an instance of a form ?

Comment: I just checked and clean does not get called on form creation. Are you sure you are not calling form valid else where?!

Comment: Did u resolve the issue?

Comment: Not yet, i added an EDIT part to the original thread. The GET piece of code is somehow calling the `clean` method when it runs the function: `get_template(template_name, using=None) [from django.template.loader.py]`

Comment: Whats in your template? how are you rendering your form?